# How does one show this is a basis for this topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal{T}(X)$ be the set of all topologies on $X$. I want to show that given a subset $S\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$, if we define $\tau_S$ as the smallest topology containing $S$, that is:

$$\tau_S=\bigcap \{\tau' \in \mathcal{T}(X) : S\subset \tau'\},$$

then a basis for $\tau_S$ is the set

$$B_S=\{A_1\cap\cdots \cap A_n : A_i\in S, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$

of all finite intersections of elements of  $S$.

Now, to show that $B_S$ is a basis we need to show that if $U\in \tau_S$ is open, and if $x\in U$, there is $B_x\in B_S$ so that $x\in B_x\subset U$.

If $U\in \tau_S$, then $U$ is an element of all topologies containing $S$, but I can't see how this implies that there are intersections of elements of $S$ inside $U$.

How can I show that $B_S$ is really a basis for this topology?

Comment: Perhaps a better way would be to show that $B_S$ is a basis for some topology, and that this topology must be smaller than $\tau_S$.  However, it also contains $S$, and hence by minimality you can conclude that the topology generated by $B_S$ is the same as that of $\tau_S$, so $B_S$ *is* the basis you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Show instead that $B_S$ is a base for some topology $\tau$ on $X$. Then show that $S\subseteq\tau$, so $\tau_S\subseteq\tau$. Finally, show that if $\tau_S\subseteq\tau'$ for some topology $\tau'$ on $X$, then $B_S\subseteq\tau'$ and hence $\tau\subseteq\tau'$; from this you can conclude that $\tau\subseteq\tau_S$.